# Find an item on a list using wildcard characters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to find a solution that finds items in a list by using wildcard characters.

For example, if i search `battle` i have to see the results of the list with these names: `1battle` `battle2` `abattlef` etc.

I know that the wildcard character in C# is `*` but with `list.IndexOf("*battle*")` it doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want help with your code, publish it here so people can indicate what's the problem.
If you want to describe a problem and get code, this is not the right place.

Comment: i didn't want to get code,but i needed some help..i don't have any idea how to do it,so i asked for this reason.sorry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below linq:

```
list.Where(str => str.Contains("battle"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following regular expression:

```
        Regex pattern = new Regex(".*battle.*");

        bool isMatch = pattern.IsMatch("battle");
```

Regex class documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming .NET3.5 or above with linq:

```
var results = list.Where(x => x.IndexOf("battle", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) > -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are required to iterate the list and match against a regular expression.

Functionality of regular expressions are implemented in: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx